# Time Machine Server on Fedora

Tags: fedora, mac, backup, osx-mountain-lion

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to/or knew of a good guide to setting up mac Time Machine backup server on a fedora 17 machine. I recently ran into an issue with my HDD and lost all of my data, so I don't want it to ever happen again, as it was quite traumatising, haha! I just want to be able to back all of my data up on my fedora machine from my mac, at scheduled times when I connect to my home network. If anyone could help, it would be fantastic, I searched around on google, but all of the ones I found were for older distros.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Here](http://kremalicious.com/ubuntu-as-mac-file-server-and-time-machine-volume/) is a good guide I have been following to setup a time machine to backup our offices macbooks. This applies to ubuntu but you can have a good understanding on how to set it up on fedora.

Comment: We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. We will delete this answer if you do not update it. Thank you!

Comment: Being able to give an answer which is a solution for a problem does not mean that I have the time to elaborate and give detailed content. I try to be active on helping people out in serverfault and to be honest I have found very little help when I needed.  I think that it is my time to stop being as active because it seems that Im always wrong by something.

Comment: I'm very sorry you feel that way. If it helps at all we try to hold everyone to the same standards. Everyone has a different experience of Server Fault; it's been extremely rare that I've obtained any help directly. Almost everything I've gleaned from SF are best practices, new possibilities, and better understandings of diverse environments (experiences I wouldn't have without the community here). I wouldn't blame you for thinking it takes too much effort to be a top contributor, the return is rarely expressed as appreciation or help when you need it. Thank you for your efforts all the same!